# Inappropriate scaling factor when editing PDF and displaying image in UIWebView

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview, scaling

I'm struggling with PDF editing so I'm starting with naive code trying to achieve the following :

- Display a PDF bundled with app
- Click on screen where I want to add my image (Signature for example)
- Reload the webview with the edited PDF

Here is my code on github : https://github.com/HRiffiod/PDFSignature.git

The problem is that my image does not display at the right position in the edited PDF. It is not random, but the farther I get from the (0,0) coordinates, the bigger the deviation, that's why I'm betting on a wrong scaling factor.

For example, this is what I get if I tap the first word and then click "Sign !" :

[image]

So this is pretty accurate. however, this is what happens if I click the last word from this PDF page (and I mean page, not this paragraph) :

[image]

That is not okay at all.

Any suggestion ?
Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

Here is a piece of code (that you can find on github) where the context rendering kicks in and might be the place I am doing it wrong :

```
// loop over PDF pages to render it
for(size_t page = 1; page <= numberOfPages; page++)
{
    //  Get the current page and page frame
    CGPDFPageRef pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, page);
    const CGRect pageFrame = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pageFrame, nil);

    //  Draw the page (flipped)
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

    // Get appropriate scale
    //CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    // As suggested in SO, the (1, -1) scale might need to be changed but couldn't get it right. Y axis is negative in order to render PDF (mandatory)
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -pageFrame.size.height);        
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, pdfPage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

    if(page == 1)
    {
        [self drawLogo];
    }
}
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Comment: I don't see in your code where you click and then do something with the clicked coordinates - frankly it would be better to integrate the relevant pieces of code into your question here. That said, do you convert from pixels to points? You get pixel coordinates and I assume use to coordinates to position the signature. As 1 pixel is 0.75 points, it's normal that the dog doesn't end up in the right place if you don't do that conversion; it'll end up about three quarters of the way from 0, 0...

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DavidvanDriessche, I updated (mostly commented) the code to make it clearer and will update my post. Your suggestion about pixel/point converting seems legit, I surely need to give it a try but is there a generic way (that works on retina and non retina devices) to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not using the appropriate scale for retina devices.

ViewController.m

```
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
```

This should be based off the device's scale.

e.g. (Assuming the y scale value needs to be negative for some reason)

```
CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]; 

CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, scale, -scale);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer ! First of all, I have to invert the y axis in order to render into PDF, I cannot change that. Unfortunately, your hint does not do the trick, it kind of zooms the PDF, but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the scale here does not seem to be the problem. Indeed, when modifying this scale, it just zooms in the PDF and it does not fit on the screen anymore. Any other idea please ?