# Drawn image over PDF is upside-down

Tags: ios, pdf, uiimage

I am trying to draw an image over an existing PDF (displayed on the screen). The final goal would be to sign the pdf anywhere.

[My sample code is here on Github](https://github.com/HRiffiod/PDFSignature)

The code (basic) works like this :

- The user clicks where he wants to draw the image
- The PDF editing occurs and the final PDF appears on screen

However the problem is that my image appears upside down. While working with PDF, I learned that you have to flip context to render, it may be related.

```
- (void)editPDFWithName:(NSString*)pdfName
{
// grab reference to bundled PDF
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:pdfName withExtension:@"pdf"]);

const size_t numberOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);

// Begin PDF context
NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRectZero, nil);

// loop over PDF pages to render it
for(size_t page = 1; page <= numberOfPages; page++)
{
    //  Get the current page and page frame
    CGPDFPageRef pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, page);
    const CGRect pageFrame = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pageFrame, nil);

    //  Draw the page (flipped)
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

    // Y axis is negative in order to render PDF (mandatory)
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -pageFrame.size.height);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, pdfPage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

    if(page == [self getCurrentPage])
    {
        // 0.75f factor to convert pixel/points
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(self.xTouchCoord*0.75f, self.yTouchCoord*0.75f, self.logo.size.width, self.logo.size.height), self.logo.CGImage);
    }

}
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
pdf = nil;

//  Save PDF
[self savePDF:data];
```

}

[I tried multiple ways to flip image as suggested on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404706/how-to-flip-uiimage-horizontally)

But the image is still flipped.

One thing I noticed is if I use the method `drawAtPoint` method on the image, it appears not flipped but does not appear at the specified position, like there is an offset ([see other post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019051/inappropriate-scaling-factor-when-editing-pdf-and-displaying-image-in-uiwebview?noredirect=1#comment57775667_35019051))

Can someone please suggest any idea ? I'm betting on the Save and Restore context methods but cannot get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found the solution :

- use `drawInRect`instead of CGContextDrawImage
- for better precision, don't forget to subtract half of the width and height to the coordinates to adjust the center :

  ```
      // 0.75f factor to convert pixel/points
      [self.logo drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.xTouchCoord*0.75f - self.logo.size.width/2, self.yTouchCoord*0.75f - self.logo.size.width/2, self.logo.size.width, self.logo.size.height)];
  ```